# WCF service parallel processing

Tags: wcf

I have a system, that request data from a WCF webservice
it is like so:

WCF1 calls WCF2, WCF2 calls WCF3 and WCF3 do its job and returns response

My problem here is some of the operations takes a long time "about 2 min" to process

So if WCF1 send a request that takes long of time, and then another request from WCF1 that should take a second, it will wait until the first request finishes

i read about the problem, some of users said to use

```
<ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode:=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.PerCall)> _
```

this doesn't solve the problem 100%

Can u please advice

Answer (score 0):

I do not think those settings will solve your problem.

From the  [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx):

> In PerCall instancing, concurrency is not relevant, because each
>   message is processed by a new InstanceContext and, therefore, never
>   more than one thread is active in the InstanceContext.

Bottom line, because you are using [PerCall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx) activation, there is no point in adding the [ConcurrencyMode.Multiple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.concurrencymode.aspx) as each incoming request will get its own instance of the service class to handle its request.

You should try to narrow down what is really causing the performance problem. Look at the underlying code that your WCF services are calling.

**EDIT**

From another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227059/does-concurrencymode-of-multiple-have-relevance-when-instancecontextmode-is-perc) post.

> **In terms of behavior**: ConcurrencyMode does not matter for a PerCall
>   service instance.
>
> **In terms of performance**: A PerCall service that is
>   ConcurrencyMode.Multiple should be slightly faster because its not
>   creating and acquiring the (unneeded) thread lock that
>   ConcurrencyMode.Single is using.

Comment: i took this configuration from this article

it says it deffers

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/configure-wcf-behaviors-using-instance-context-mode-lapidus-leonid

Comment: I read that article. My answer still stands. A Performance gain is negligible. You should should try to determine the underlying causes of your performance problems. Why do you need to call 3 WCF services when only one of them is really doing something.

Comment: yea i know it sounds strange, but in our company, there is a lot of firewalls so..

Anyway, even if i call one to one, the problem will still exists, because service will call a service.... which is one client only will call the service, so the problem will be the same

So if i understand u well, this configuration will not affect the performance, and i should check the service code not the service configuration?

Comment: Correct. You should look at the service code and determine the root cause of the performance issue.